# Is it possible to solve this equation for "x" analytically?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

The following equation has come up in my research. I would like to solve the following for $x$:

$$x\prod_i^n \left(1-d_i\right)^{\left(1-b_i\right)c} = \prod_i^n \left( \frac{a_i}{x} \right)^{b_i}$$

Any idea how I can go about tackling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{i}^{n}(1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c} = \dfrac{1}{x} \prod_{i}^{n}(\dfrac{a_i}{x})^{b_i}$$

The right side

$$ \dfrac{1}{x} \prod_{i}^{n}(\dfrac{a_i}{x})^{b_i} = x^{-1-{\sum_{i}^{n}b_i}}\prod_{i}^{n}(a_i^{b_i}) \therefore $$

$$x^{1+{\sum_{i}^{n}b_i}}=\dfrac{\prod_{i}^{n}(a_i^{b_i})}{\prod_{i}^{n}(1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}} \implies x =  (\dfrac{\prod_{i}^{n}(a_i^{b_i})}{\prod_{i}^{n}(1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}})^{\dfrac{1}{1+{\sum_{i}^{n}b_i}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here.
$$
x^{1+\sum_i^n b_i}=\prod_i^n \frac{a_i^{b_i}}{(1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}}
$$
So
$$
x=\big(\prod_i^n \frac{a_i^{b_i}}{(1-d_i)^{(1-b_i)c}}\big)^{\frac{1}{1+\sum_i^n b_i}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is of the form $x^{-1-\sum{b_i}}$=const which is easy to solve.

Comment: Sorry, I put the x on the wrong side and have edited it. Is this answer still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\left[\prod_i^n \frac{a_i}{\left(1-d_i\right)^{\left(1-b_i\right)c}}\right]^{1/(1+\sum_i b_i)}$$